# ASP.Net 5 (MVC 6) - Accessing session object in view via a wrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a class

```
public class SessionService : ISessionService
{
    public const string SessionUserKey = "UserViewModel";

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    private ISession _session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

    public SessionService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public UserViewModel LoggedInUser
    {
        get
        {
            return _session.GetObjectFromJson<UserViewModel>(SessionUserKey);
        }
        set
        {
            _session.SetObjectAsJson(SessionUserKey, value);
        }
    }

    public void Destroy()
    {
        _session.Clear();
    }
}
```

An instance of this class is injected to my controller like this:

Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<ISessionService, SessionService>();
```

AccountController.cs

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserAccountService _accountService;
    private readonly ISessionService _sessionService;

    public AccountController(IUserAccountService accountService, ISessionService sessionService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
        _sessionService = sessionService;
    }
}
```

However, in my view I want to access the currently logged in user like this:

```
 @if(SomeClass.LoggedInUser != null){
 // code removed for brevity
 }
```

How can I achieve this without making the `LoggedInUser` property of my `SessionService` class static. It seems like something needs to me made static to have an access like this. But I was wondering if there was a better way to accomplish this. And no, I don't want to use the `ViewBag`.

**I am not using ASP.Net Identity**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `@inject` if you want to inject services in your views using DI:

```
@inject WebProject.Services.ISessionService CurrentSessionService

@if (CurrentSessionService.LoggedInUser != null)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is it! Although it should be `ISessionService` instead of `IUserAccountService`. So I have `@inject  WebProject.Services.ISessionService CurrentSessionService`, and `@if(CurrentSessionService.LoggedInUser !=null){//...}` in my view file. Thanks a lot.